# 2 timers, one n seconds behind the other

Tags: c#, timer, mfc

Here's my problem: I have a timer that has an interval of 5 minutes.  What I want is to be notified that there is only 30 seconds left on the timer so I can enable/disable certain controls (winforms in c#).  I'm assuming that I would need 2 timers for this, maybe a new MyTimer class that would have these 2 timers as data members.  The first timer would be for 5 minutes and the second be fore 4.5 minutes.  The second timer would raise an event that I would listen to.  Does anyone have any better ideas on this?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should show the code that you have so far for performing this task, and then we can correct / improve it (if needed).  That will get you better answers in the end.

Comment: How about putting the 5 minute timer to 30 seconds and keeping track of how many times it has procced? 9 times = 4.5 minutes, 10 times = 5 minutes?

Comment: The second timer would *not* be 4.5 mintues.  That would make it correct on the first firing and then .5 minutes behind on the second.  It needs to also be on a 5 minute interval, but just be started .5 minutes earlier.  (Or have the interval change from 4.5 to 5 on the first firing, or something along those lines.)

Comment: How did this question get `c#` and `mfc` (a C++ framework) tags?  What language and framework are you really using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Floris Velleman mentioned above, it would probably be best to use 1 timer that increments at a minimum time base, such as 30 seconds or even 1 second.  Then use a counter and some condition statements that will react at certain times.  Having 2 timers would require synchronizing between the two, which could cause some problems.

For example, with an interval of 1 second, you could do this:

```
int TimerInterval = 60 * 5; // 5 minutes
int NotifyTime = 30; // 30 seconds
int counter = 0;

// timer interval is set to 1 second
private void callback_MyTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter--;

    if (counter == NotifyTime)
    {
        // notify that 30 seconds are left...
    }

    // restart the counter for 5 minutes
    if (counter <= 0)
    {
        counter = TimerInterval;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What a great solution.  I wish I had thought of that.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Waitable Timer objects, and the `SetWaitableTimer` function in particular, allow the due time and period to be controlled separately.

The MSDN documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687008.aspx).